# SQL table for protein database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I am working as a bioinformatic engineer, and I work a lot with the UNIPROT database. It contains around 6 million entries in a huge file.

Now I use a method that I made an "index" file, for some ID entries, and when I want to access a protein, I grep the entry from the index file, and then search the huge database file with that index. It takes around 0.3 sec to search a given protein.

I am searching for a faster method, and found SQL tables. I don't yet know anything about them, so I would have a couple if question about them.

Can I achieve the same thing with SQL table faster? If yes what kind of data structure would you suggest me? Any good site where i can get a good tutorial about it? Also I am working in python, so I am interested in about the integration of SQL in python. As far as I know there are some importable modules for SQL in python. Am I wrong? Can I do this in python only, or do I have to use "out of the box" methods?

TLDR: Can I achieve an ID --> protein (maybe some additional information) table with like 6 million entries, where I can search a specific ID in like 0.01 second with SQL inside python?

Comment: Look at SQLAlchemy, it provides a generic way to use various relational data sources from Python. But you would have to export everything into the database first. If your purpose is search, you might also consider using ElasticSearch, which is optimized for efficient search in semi-structured data.

Comment: Thank you! I ll look into that! Do you maybe know about the search time in a million entry dataset?

Comment: Depends on what you are searching. If you search on an indexed entity, it's faster. If you search for.a number of various properties at once, I would rather go for ElasticSearch than for relational DB.

Comment: I imagined 2 columns, one for ID one for the protein. I would lile to search for the ID and get the protein. For a start this would be nice if i would be able to access a protein in fraction of seconds

Comment: Possibly not! SQL is principally optimized for relational data.

Comment: How big is the current file you are searching with grep?

Comment: It has the same amount of entries, so its 6 million. But each entry is a one line 6 char ID. The big database file may contain 100 lines for one protein (one entry)

Comment: If you can search by ID which is 6-char field then an index on this field is possible. Searching by a string contained in a protein itself would be a different story though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your basic question "a specific ID in 10 ms?" is definitely "yes."

There are many good ways to access SQL databases from Python. The most basic, the MySQL Connector, is described here. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html

I guess you're working with the `idmapping.dat` table described here. ftp://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase/idmapping/README

Apparently the mapping table has three columns:

1. UniProtKB-AC
2. ID_type
3. ID

According to the sample table on the Uniprot web site, entries in the table look like this:

```
UniProtKB-AC  ID_type       ID
Q6GZX4        GeneID        2947773
Q6GZX4        KEGG           vg:2947773
Q6GZX3        UniProtKB-ID   002L_FRG3G
Q6GZX3        GI             49237299
Q197F8        UniProtKB-ID   002R_IIV3
Q197F8        GI             106073503
Q197F7        UniProtKB-ID   003L_IIV3
Q197F7        GI             106073504
```

To build a SQL table to search this efficiently try using a SQL table like this:

```
ID_type       part of primary key
ID            part of primary key
UniProtKB_AC
```

Then you can run queries such as this very quickly.

```
SELECT UniProtKB_AC FROM idmapping WHERE ID_type='GI' AND ID LIKE '10607%'
```

The secret to effective SQL is indexing.  Having some acquaintances working in bioinformatics, I know there's been a lot of work in this field.

I suggest this table definition for your idmapping table.

```
CREATE TABLE `idmapping` (
    `UniProtKB_AC` CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    `ID_type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `ID` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID_type`, `ID`),
    INDEX `ID_lookup` (`UniProtKB_AC`, `ID_type`, `ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci';
```

It contains two indexes. One is optimized to look up items by ID_type and ID. The other is optimized to look up by the UniprotKB keys.

Here is a SQL Fiddle example. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ab10/2/0

**Edit** You asked about including protein sequences. My answer has two parts.

1. it is possible to include protein sequences in the database.
2. you probably should not include them in the same *table* as the id lookup table, due to a design principle called [*database normalization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Now, it looks like protein sequences these days are represented by one letter per amino acid. A bit of search engine clicking finds, for example, that [the protein with the code `Q197F8` (a virus) has this sequence](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q197F8.fasta) of 458 amino acids.

```
MASNTVSAQGGSNRPVRDFSNIQDVAQFLLFDPIWNEQPGSIVPWKMNREQALAERYPEL
QTSEPSEDYSGPVESLELLPLEIKLDIMQYLSWEQISWCKHPWLWTRWYKDNVVRVSAIT
FEDFQREYAFPEKIQEIHFTDTRAEEIKAILETTPNVTRLVIRRIDDMNYNTHGDLGLDD
LEFLTHLMVEDACGFTDFWAPSLTHLTIKNLDMHPRWFGPVMDGIKSMQSTLKYLYIFET
YGVNKPFVQWCTDNIETFYCTNSYRYENVPRPIYVWVLFQEDEWHGYRVEDNKFHRRYMY
STILHKRDTDWVENNPLKTPAQVEMYKFLLRISQLNRDGTGYESDSDPENEHFDDESFSS
GEEDSSDEDDPTWAPDSDDSDWETETEEEPSVAARILEKGKLTITNLMKSLGFKPKPKKI
QSIDRYFCSLDSNYNSEDEDFEYDSDSEDDDSDSEDDC
```

You have two potential ways to store that in a SQL style database. One is to create a table with two columns: `UniProtKB_AC`, name, and `Sequence.` This table will have one row per indexed protein. It will represent the sequence as a character string.  It will look something like this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ec9dd/4/0)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sequence` (
  `UniProtKB_AC` char(6) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Sequence` text NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

You can do queries like this:

```
 SELECT idmapping.UniProtKB_AC, sequence.Sequence
   FROM idmapping
   LEFT JOIN sequence ON idmapping.UniProtKB_AC = sequence.UniProtKB_AC
  WHERE ID_type='GI' AND ID LIKE '10607%'
```

to get sequences of proteins matching a particular id query.

The other approach is to create a sequence table with one row per amino acid. It would look something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sequenceDetail` (
  `UniProtKB_AC` char(6) NOT NULL,
  `SequenceNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AminoAcid` char(1) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The Sequence Number item is a number from 1 to 458 (in the case of this example). This table would allow such things as retrieving the sequence in reverse order.

```
 SELECT idmapping.UniProtKB_AC, sequenceDetail.AminoAcid
   FROM idmapping
   LEFT JOIN sequenceDetail ON idmapping.UniProtKB_AC = sequenceDetail.UniProtKB_AC
  WHERE ID_type='GI' AND ID LIKE '10607%'
  ORDER BY sequenceDetail.SequenceNumber DESC
```

Comment: Thanks you for your respose! Is it possible to include the protein sequence in a table like this as well with SQL?

Comment: See my edit. Things get interesting when you start searching for proteins with matching subsequences, especially when you want to allow for insertion, deletion, and change mutations. You should look up algorithms like the Levenshtein Distance.

Comment: One more question if i may. Currently i have 92524243 proteins. How much query time can i expect in your solution if i want to obtain the sequence of the Q197F8 you mentioned?

Comment: If your tables are indexed correctly, and your MySQL server has >= 4gib of RAM and reasonably good disk drives, a single lookup should take 10-20 ms from a table that size.  Now, loading the tables is a different question. That may take a weekend.